# checkbox and radio button is not showing perfect in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I m creating custom checkbox and radio button in pure css but they are not showing perfectly in IE7 .

any body help in

code is there please check it

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
<fieldset>

<legend id="title1" class="desc">
Select a Choice
</legend>

<div>
<span>
<input id="Field1_0" name="Field1" type="radio" class="field radio"  checked="checked">
<label class="choice" for="Field1_0">
First Choice</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="Field1_1" name="Field1" type="radio" class="field radio">
<label class="choice" for="Field1_1">
Second Choice</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="Field1_2" name="Field1" type="radio" class="field radio">
<label class="choice" for="Field1_2">
Third Choice</label>
</span>
</div>
</fieldset>
</li>


<li>
<fieldset>

<legend id="title2" class="desc">
Check All That Apply
</legend>

<div>
<span>
<input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox" checked="checked">
<label class="choice" for="Field2">First Choice</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox">
<label class="choice" for="Field3">Second Choice</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox">
<label class="choice" for="Field4">Third Choice</label>
</span>
</div>
</fieldset>
</li>
</ul>​
```

**Css**

```
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'],
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] 
{
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 18px;
}

li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'] + label,
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    margin: 0;
    clear: none;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;
    /* Make look clickable because they are */
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(https://css-tricks.com/wufoo/themes/customradiosandcheckboxes/off.png) left center no-repeat;
}

li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(https://css-tricks.com/wufoo/themes/customradiosandcheckboxes/radio.png);
}
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(https://css-tricks.com/wufoo/themes/customradiosandcheckboxes/check.png);
}​
```

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Vsvg2/79/) http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Vsvg2/79/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**:checked** is the property of css3 which not supported by IE8 & below browsers. But your can achieve this with http://selectivizr.com/ JS which support all css3 pseudo selector for IE

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, `:checked` is a css3 pseudoclass.

You could still use an attribute selector though like so:

```
input[type='checkbox'][checked='checked']
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that only checkboxes that have `checked="checked"` in the HTML will be selected. The user toggling checkboxes on the page won't affect what's selected.